# Replacing a None value in a list with an index in Python

Tags: python

In this question I have to substitute all `None` values in a list with the mean of the number before and after the None value. So if i have a list with

```
[1, None, 3, None, 7]
```

The desired output is

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
```

My current code:

```
def substitution(L):
    
    result = []
    
    for i in L:
        if i is None:
            result.append(L[3])
            
        else:
            result.append(i)
            
    return result

list = [4, None, 6, 2, 3, None, 8, 11]
test = substitution(list)
print(test)
```

My output makes no sense, I only came as far as to substitute the Nones with an index but can't figure out how to get the mean of the index before and after it and then print it.

```
[4, 2, 6, 2, 3, 2, 8, 11]
```

The desired output is as follows:

```
[4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 5.5, 8, 11]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Question about edge conditions - if the None is at the front or back of the list, what happens? If there are multiple None's in a row, what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a for loop, you can loop over the *indices* (the position of a given element in the list) instead of the actual *elements* of the list:

```py
def substitution(L):
    
    result = []
    
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if L[i] is None:
            result.append((L[i-1] + L[i+1])/2)
            
        else:
            result.append(L[i])
            
    return result
```